# Power Bi Super slow Query needs a performance boost

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerquery

Our Subscription table is contains around 40k entries. I am trying to calculate the Monthly-Recurring.Dim is a simple calendar table to map the date ranges start and end to the days.

```
Sumx('Subscription Clean',
CALCULATE(
    SUMX(
        SUMMARIZE(
            FILTER(
                CROSSJOIN(
                    'Subscription Clean',Dim
                ),
                Dim[Date] <= 'Subscription Clean'[End At] &&
                Dim[Date] > 'Subscription Clean'[Start At]
                
            ),
             'Subscription Clean'[Duration total],
            'Subscription Clean'[Duration],
            'Subscription Clean'[End At],
            'Subscription Clean'[Start At],
            'Subscription Clean'[Price]),

        DIVIDE(DIVIDE(
            'Subscription Clean'[Price],DATEDIFF([Start At],[End At],DAY)+1
        ),1.19) % Tax of 19
    )
 )
)
```

The data looks like this

| Sales Id | Product name | created At | end at | Cancelled At | Price in € | Duration |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | bananas | 01.01.2021 | 01.03.2021 | 28.02.2021 | 20.00 | 2 |
| 2 | apples | 01.02.2021 | 01.05.2021 | null | 90€ | 3 |

The output should be like this for the mmr each month 10€ come from the first position for the months {1,2}
Each price will be distributed between the dates Start and End.

```
jan = 10   
feb = 40   
mar = 30   
apr = 30  
may = 0
```

The DAX query is working properly but hell a slow. Is there any way to improve the performance? Further the calculated measure will be used to do more calculations and needed to be loaded in memory if possible for quick access. Maybe anyone knows how to do it properly and I can leech some good hints ;)

Comment: Add some sample/dummy data and desired output

Comment: Thank you for the response.
I added some data . Thanks in advance Sir.